# Laravel a form isn't reset after successful submit

Tags: laravel

This is my controller:

```
class GuestbookController extends Controller
{
    public function viewAll(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->method() === 'POST') {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'username' => 'required|string|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\d]+$/',
                'email' => 'required|string|email',
                'homepage' => 'nullable|string|url',
                'text' => 'string',
                'captcha' => 'required|captcha',
            ],
                [
                    'captcha.captcha' => 'The captcha is incorrect',
                    'username.regex' => 'Use English letters and digits only',
                ]);

            $message = new Message();

            $message->username = $request->get('username');

            $message->email = $request->get('email');

            $message->homepage = $request->get('homepage');

            $message->text = strip_tags($request->get('text'));

            $message->ip = $request->ip();

            $message->browser = get_browser($request->header('User-Agent'))->browser;

            $message->save();
        }

        $messages = Message::sortable(['created_at' => 'desc'])->paginate(25);

        return view('Guestbook.viewAll', [
            'newMessage' => new Message(),
            'messages' => $messages
        ]);
    }
}
```

I am using this [plugin](https://github.com/dwightwatson/bootstrap-form). viewAll handles both GET and POST requests, but the problem is that the form isn't reset when I successfully submit data keeping all the previous input values.

I've checked what the server sends and it seems like it sends inputs with last values in them. I've no idea what to do, please help!

View:

```
@extends('base')

@section('title', 'Guestbook')

@section('baseContent')
    {!! BootForm::open(['model' => $newMessage]) !!}
    {!! BootForm::text('username') !!}

    {!! BootForm::email('email') !!}

    {!! BootForm::text('homepage') !!}

    {!! BootForm::textarea('text') !!}

    {!! captcha_img() !!}

    {!! BootForm::text('captcha') !!}

    {!! BootForm::submit('Send') !!}
    {!! BootForm::close() !!}
    @if (count($messages) > 0)
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td>@sortablelink('username', 'Username')</td>
                <td>@sortablelink('email', 'Email')</td>
                <td>Homepage</td>
                <td>@sortablelink('created_at', 'Data added')</td>
                <td>Message</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($messages as $message)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $message->username }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $message->email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $message->homepage }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $message->created_at }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $message->message }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    @else
        There is nothing to display here.
    @endif
    {!! $messages->appends(\Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
@endsection
```

See all code [here](https://github.com/Razip/LaravelGuestBookTestProject).

Answer (score 2):

BootForm is compiled like this

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username" class="control-label col-md-2">Username</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="text" value={{old('username')}} name="username" class="form-control">
</div>
```

The `old('params')` is a helper method which keeps the previous inputs in session. And secondly, you have model associated with it.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have any ideas on how to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I've investigated how FormBuilder's getValueAttribute method works and it seems that it intends to use value from the request, then the one that was passed as an argument, then the model's (if the model generally exists).